# Getting rectangle/circle intersection points using boost library

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

Is it possible to get rectangle x circle intersection points with `boost`? As far as I can see `boost` has an intersection function:

```
template<typename Geometry1, typename Geometry2, typename GeometryOut>
bool intersection(Geometry1 const & geometry1, Geometry2 const & geometry2, GeometryOut & geometry_out)
```

But I can't find how can I even construct a circular geometry. I mean, I can create a polygon with lots of vertices, but it's not the kind of representation I'm looking for

Comment: @rafix07 please restore your answer, it's helpful. I'll leave mine as well because my answer is simpler and answers more generally to the question. However, your answer is highly valuable to any future user who is content with polygon approximation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to get circle using boost you can use `boost::geometry::buffer` algorithm. Details [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/buffer/buffer_7_with_strategies.html).

You need to pass point as input geometry (center of your circle) and radius as *distance_strategy*. Full test code below

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f862b8f4db0179bb)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/io/io.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/geometries.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> point;
    typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<point> polygon;

    const double buffer_distance = 1.0; // radius of circle
    const int points_per_circle = 36;
    boost::geometry::strategy::buffer::distance_symmetric<double> distance_strategy(buffer_distance);
    boost::geometry::strategy::buffer::join_round join_strategy(points_per_circle);
    boost::geometry::strategy::buffer::end_round end_strategy(points_per_circle);
    boost::geometry::strategy::buffer::point_circle circle_strategy(points_per_circle);
    boost::geometry::strategy::buffer::side_straight side_strategy;

    boost::geometry::model::multi_polygon<polygon> result;

    point pt;
    boost::geometry::read_wkt("POINT(5 5)", pt); // center of circle

    boost::geometry::buffer(pt, result,
                distance_strategy, side_strategy,
                join_strategy, end_strategy, circle_strategy);
    // first item of result is circle with 1 radius and (5,5) point as center
    // result should have 1 polygon
    polygon rect; // your rectangle
    boost::geometry::read_wkt("POLYGON((3 3,3 7,5 7,5 3,3 3))",rect);

    std::deque<polygon> intersectionGeometry;
    boost::geometry::intersection(rect,result.front(),intersectionGeometry);
    if (intersectionGeometry.size() == 1)
        std::cout << boost::geometry::wkt(intersectionGeometry.front()) << std::endl; // intersection

    std::cout << boost::geometry::wkt(result) << "\n";
}
```

Prints the intersection as

```
POLYGON((5 4,4.82635 4.01519,4.65798 4.06031,4.5 4.13397,4.35721 4.23396,4.23396 4.35721,4.13397 4.5,4.06031 4.65798,4.01519 4.82635,4 5,4.01519 5.17365,4.06031 5.34202,4.13397 5.5,4.23396 5.64279,4.35721 5.76604,4.5 5.86603,4.65798 5.93969,4.82635 5.98481,5 6,5 4))
```

And you can see the `result` of the buffer is:

```
MULTIPOLYGON(((6 5,5.98481 4.82635,5.93969 4.65798,5.86603 4.5,5.76604 4.35721,5.64279 4.23396,5.5 4.13397,5.34202 4.06031,5.17365 4.01519,5 4,4.82635 4.01519,4.65798 4.06031,4.5 4.13397,4.35721 4.23396,4.23396 4.35721,4.13397 4.5,4.06031 4.65798,4.01519 4.82635,4 5,4.01519 5.17365,4.06031 5.34202,4.13397 5.5,4.23396 5.64279,4.35721 5.76604,4.5 5.86603,4.65798 5.93969,4.82635 5.98481,5 6,5.17365 5.98481,5.34202 5.93969,5.5 5.86603,5.64279 5.76604,5.76604 5.64279,5.86603 5.5,5.93969 5.34202,5.98481 5.17365,6 5)))
```

I added the picture as output, the dark semicircle is intersection geometry:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

A polygon approximation is the usual approach.

The easy way to construct one is to use `buffer` with the `point_circle` strategy:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/strategies/strategy_buffer_point_circle.html